# remove empty tabs wordpress 2021 solution

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tabs on some product page need to be but on other no, so how to hide these tabs without any content from single product details?

trying to use this code

```
// Remove Empty Tabs
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'yikes_woo_remove_empty_tabs', 20, 1 );

function yikes_woo_remove_empty_tabs( $tabs ) {

    if ( ! empty( $tabs ) ) {
        foreach ( $tabs as $title => $tab ) {
            if ( empty( $tab['content'] ) ) {
                unset( $tabs[ $title ] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

but it doesnt work

```
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php
```

trying to modyfi code to:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 

'yikes_woo_remove_empty_tabs', 98 );

function yikes_woo_remove_empty_tabs( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

            if ( empty ($tabs['wcpoa_product_tab']['content']) ) {
                unset( $tabs['wcpoa_product_tab'] );
            } 
            return $tabs;

}
```

but with this code tab named wcpoa_product_tab is invisible with or without content...

Comment: Towards the bottom of [this page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/) in the documentation that is specifically addressed.

Comment: yes i know but there is no solution to hide tabs with no content